How to download the file from WHATSAPP API that received via webhook in the form of JSON?
We are using third-party API services to connect WHATSAPP instances and watching the webhook to download any audio or voice file for later transcription. The response we get from the webhook is in the form of JSON. The code sample is below:
{
            "instance_id": "670F8EB71BCC8",
            "data": {
                "event": "messages.upsert",
                "data": {
                    "messages": [
                        {
                            "key": {
                                "remoteJid": "923411363215@s.whatsapp.net",
                                "fromMe": false,
                                "id": "3EB0C786C5ECC3DB8EF55E"
                            },
                            "messageTimestamp": 1730370494,
                            "pushName": "Gulshan Fatima",
                            "broadcast": false,
                            "message": {
                                "audioMessage": {
                                    "url": "https://mmg.whatsapp.net/v/t62.7117-24/23769379_1887584434985641_7294817018279328005_n.enc?ccb=11-4&oh=01_Q5AaIE6U4-DRcQ07AFaPQvh-xq7p3-hj5NfmgySTm-o6zykg&oe=674A9F4D&_nc_sid=5e03e0&mms3=true",
                                    "mimetype": "audio/ogg; codecs=opus",
                                    "fileSha256": "q1J4mSqx0vE8oNQxqSdiLiT4UqeJoDm9Pcx/5o5goNg=",
                                    "fileLength": "17290",
                                    "seconds": 7,
                                    "ptt": false,
                                    "mediaKey": "HkWlGGL7T4A+pN5S7Dc1M/aIoKZUM+plEsY+UbFoBE0=",
                                    "fileEncSha256": "faJu9zOAcGnB+wCvqwk/Rs/0AOkITRiPCOAw2xY1TQ8=",
                                    "directPath": "/v/t62.7117-24/23769379_1887584434985641_7294817018279328005_n.enc?ccb=11-4&oh=01_Q5AaIE6U4-DRcQ07AFaPQvh-xq7p3-hj5NfmgySTm-o6zykg&oe=674A9F4D&_nc_sid=5e03e0",
                                    "mediaKeyTimestamp": "1730365220",
                                    "contextInfo": {
                                        "ephemeralSettingTimestamp": "1730363593",
                                        "disappearingMode": {
                                            "initiator": "CHANGED_IN_CHAT"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "waveform": "AAAAASsnGwwAAAAFL0AyLSk6KwQAJQAAAkM5JzAxHUk4LwA7Ezc2ODMBOzEFOwxERAYqPzoVADM8NT8qJDRGEQ==",
                                    "viewOnce": false
                                },
                                "messageContextInfo": {
                                    "deviceListMetadata": {
                                        "senderKeyHash": "UGQQlAh12HnI7Q==",
                                        "senderTimestamp": "1730363426",
                                        "recipientKeyHash": "M3OjUavSOixxMw==",
                                        "recipientTimestamp": "1729072828"
                                    },
                                    "deviceListMetadataVersion": 2,
                                    "messageSecret": "0PAvJrpZ0v+OEKdfOoJuOp9K7rf5+VMhqFs/mnMwxAg="
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "notify"
                }
            }
        }

When we send an audio file from WHATSAPP the API sends proper data to the webhook with a JSON property called audioMessage inside the full JSON. That property had a field url that holds the file URL if we are correct.
The URL looks like this:
https://mmg.whatsapp.net/v/t62.7117-24/23769379_1887584434985641_7294817018279328005_n.enc?ccb=11-4&oh=01_Q5AaIE6U4-DRcQ07AFaPQvh-xq7p3-hj5NfmgySTm-o6zykg&oe=674A9F4D&_nc_sid=5e03e0&mms3=true
But when we try to download the file it downloads a file in .enc format. Can you please tell us how we can get the .oga or .mpga file from the JSON? I think we need to decrypt something we don't know. Our target is to download this audio file and transcribe it for AI.

Any news about this? I am facing the same challenge! Please help!

I was browsing the web and encountered this repo which is 3yrs old, but it looks like a real answer to our question:
Decode Whatsapp .enc files using mediaKey
The idea here is to create a n8n Node that can do the same thing.

Does anyone know how to do this in JAVA?
